# Printf changing memory values

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to do some fixed point vector math and it seems that whenever I print anything, doesn't seem to matter what. The value of my vectors change. The code is compiled using ZDSII developer studio from Zilog.

I have a struct defined like so

```
typedef struct {
    long x;
    long y;
} vector;
```

The values inside the struct are initialized in a function

```
void initVector( vector * vec, int x, int y ) {
    vec -> x = (long) x << 14;
    vec -> y = (long) y << 14;
}
```

In my main function I have

```
int main() {
    vector * vector1;

    initVector( vector1, 1, 2 );
    printf( "foo" ); // this prints alright
    printf( "%d , %d", vector1 -> x >> 14, vector1 -> y >> 14 ); //garbage
    ...

    ...
}
```

Which prints garbage. The values will change depending on the number of printf statements before the printf where I actually print the values.

Comment: This question is asked at least 10 times per day, with different flavours. Vote to close as too localized.

Comment: Not the problem but a suggestion, why the cast in `initVector`?, use `long x, long y` instead and `vec -> x = x << 14L;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `vector1` uninitialised,

```
vector * vector1;

initVector( vector1, 1, 2 );
```

so the `initVector` invokes undefined behaviour.

Make it

```
vector vector1;
initVector(&vector1, 1, 2);
```

or

```
vector * vector1 = malloc(sizeof *vector1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't allocate memory for `vector1` to point at, so the code in `initVector()` is overwriting something random and causing undefined behavior.

Your code should be:

```
vector vector1;  /* NOT a pointer! */

initVector(&vector1, 1, 2);
printf( "foo" ); // this prints alright
printf( "%d , %d", vector1.x >> 14, vector1.y >> 14 );
```

To make the API easier to use, consider treating the `vector` structure as a value, and do:

```
vector initVector(int x, int y)
{
  vector v;
  v.x = (long) x << 14;
  v.y = (long) y << 14;
  return v;
}
```

This makes the code easier to use, and removes the risk for this particular error:

```
int main(void)
{
  vector vector1 = initVector(1, 2);
  printf("%d, %d\n", vector1.x >> 14, vector1.y >> 14);
}
```

Comment: Won't v go out of scope when returning to main? Ah sorry I missed the last code block.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate memory for `vector1`, for example:

```
int main()
{
    vector vector1;

    initVector( &vector1, 1, 2 );
    printf( "%d , %d", vector1.x >> 14, vector1.y >> 14 ); //no garbage :-)
}
```